# Icon not taking on desktop, but taking everywhere else

Tags: objective-c, macos, icons

I have an alias (also tested this whole process with a symlink and same behavior) file on my desktop, it points to an app bundle. I have dragged this alias file to my dock. In this app bundle I changed the icon (by changing the icns file contained within it), after a `killall Dock` `killall Finder` it updates my dock. However my alias file on the desktop does not update. If I right click and do "Get Info" on my alias file it shows the updated icon which is so weird, becuase the desktop is not showing this updated icon.

The icon does update if I move the alias file from the desktop to another folder. But as soon as I move the alias back to the desktop it reverts.

So then I resorted to objective-c: I have changed the icon on the app bundle it points to with this code, same effect as above (, after killall's it updates all places except desktop, and dragging it to a new folder updates it, and on drag back it reverts).

```
iconPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: blah/blah/blah];
icon = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: iconPath];

filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: blah/blah/blah];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon: icon forFile: filePath options: 0]
```

I tried using this code to set the alias file icon as well, and same affect, it takes everywhere except desktop.

If I rename the alias file on desktop to something new, the updated icon shows, if i revert the alias name to the original name, the non-updated icon shows. There seems to be a history with file path and icon. Does anyone know how to make the icon update?

Here is a screenshot of the situation, the get info window on left is the get info item of the alias file on desktop.

[image]

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32339160/2648673

Comment: Thanks you @xhruso00 checking right away!! :) I struggled with this for a long time! Man it looks like you weren't up voted there how bogus!

Comment: Drats its not working :(

Comment: Use "qlmanage -r cache". Looks like that the small icon is generated by quicklook and being cached. Also the source has something with "IKImageBrowser" namely "shouldUseIKFinderMode". Google "IKImageBrowser cache"

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597287/ikimagebrowserview-thumbnail-problem

Comment: Thanks @xhruso00 I'll try that tonight and let you know how it goes :)